# Non-English characters appear as ? marks

Tags: java, internet-explorer, unicode

In my Servlet application I'm passing a french text as a URL parameter.
For Firefox it works fine, but for IE9 it shows me ? marks.
Why is that and how can I solve that?

Comment: There are many things that could cause that. You need to make sure all things in between the client and your program are using the same encoding. It is up to you to pinpoint the part where it breaks...

Comment: use url encoding to encode the URL rather then sending the text as it is

Comment: This sounds like a character encoding issue. The response containing the pound sign is being sent in the UTF-8 character set, but is being interpreted in a different character set.

Check what character encoding you are specifying for your JSP.

Comment: Yes I'm using UTF-8. This happens only for the IE.

Comment: Non-ASCII characters are not allowed to be un-encoded in URLs.  They must be url-encoded, and even charset-encoded in a known charset (since URLs can't specify their own charsets).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a web browser charset problem?
Have you try set `<meta charset='utf-8'>`?

Comment: I have added '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>'

Comment: browsers also evaluate the http header, obey their preferences and analyze the content in deciding on which charset to use. iirc, your best bet are the http headers.